# QLabel with automatic scaling

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I need a Qt widget that displays plain text that scales automatically. This means when I resize the window that has this widget in its layout, font size is adjusted to the size of the widget to display the text in font as big as possible to fit in the size that layout dictates. Word wrap is a likely bonus.

I think, someone has already implemented such widget, but I couldn't google it.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it on the resize event of your window:

```
void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*)
{
    QFont f = label->font(); //Get label font

    QFontMetrics metrics(f);
    QSize size = metrics.size(0, label->text()); //Get size of text
    float factorw = label->width() / (float)size.width(); //Get the width factor
    float factorh = label->height() / (float)size.height(); //Get the height factor

    float factor = qMin(factorw, factorh); //To fit contents in the screen select as factor
                                           //the minimum factor between width and height

    f.setPointSizeF(f.pointSizeF() * factor); //Set font size
    label->setFont(f); //Set the adjusted font to the label
}
```

Comment: Don't know if it's just me (using Qt 5.7) but this produces insanely huge text. This is probably due to the length of the text (which is part of the calculation) but it's also due to other factors - resizing policy of the label for example.